# Return array and variable from function in c

Tags: arrays, c, function

I have code some thing like this:

```
void func1(){
// some processing
 rle(); 
 // some processing
rle();
}

int rle( , ){

 float fioutPutt[100]; 
 int fioutSize[100];
 // some processing and then save the result in fioutPutt[] and fioutSize[]
}
```

How can I receive these arrays in func1() ?

Comment: You add them as arguments, like `float f[]` or, if you prefer, `float* f`

Comment: If you really want to return them, you need to package them in a `struct`. You can't return arrays. [Example](https://godbolt.org/z/c3P3b5G87)

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to return the values, you need to package them in a `struct`. You can only return a single object or a pointer to a dynamically allocated array.

In your case I'd recommend passing a pointer to the first element in an array of `putt`/`size` pairs along with the size of the array. The `rle` function can then populate the array and when `rle` returns, the values will be available to `func1`.

Example:

```c
#include <stddef.h>

// define a putt/size pair:
typedef struct PuttSize PuttSize;
struct PuttSize {
    float putt;
    int size;
};

// take a PuttSize* and the number of elements in the array:
void rle(PuttSize psd[], size_t size) {
    // some processing and then save the result in psd
    for(size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        psd[i].putt = ...;
        psd[i].size = ...;
    }
}

void func1(void) {
    PuttSize psd[100]; // define the array

    // some processing
    rle(psd, sizeof psd / sizeof *psd); // .. and pass it in along with the size
    // some processing
    rle(psd, sizeof psd / sizeof *psd);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to get the data from arrays called in a function.
One simple way would be to pass them as arguments to the function itself:

```
void func1(){
// some processing
 float fioutPutt[100]; 
 int fioutSize[100];
 rle(fioutPutt, fioutSize); 
 // some processing
 rle(fioutPutt, fioutSize);
}

int rle(float fioutPutt[] , int fioutSize[]){

 //Operations that use fioutPutt[] and fioutSize[]
 // some processing and then save the result in fioutPutt[] and fioutSize[]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the `func1` signature in this way:

```
void func1(float *array1, int *array2);
```

So that you can write in `rle` function:

```
func1(fioutPutt, fioutSize);
```

Note that the arrays you will receive in `func1` are just a copy of those processed in `rle`.

As you can see, what you are asking is possible, but you can better understand that maybe you are trying to do an useless thing. I suggest you to try and change the behaviour of your algorithm.